# Issue with adding app option

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, app, picture-library

I am using SP Online and I was going to create a picture library to store an image, and then when I went to gear icon --> add an app I get the different view:

[image]

I did a bid of search but the only option I have is just adding normal document library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to add picture library in SharePoint online modern experience (new add an app experience):

1. Go to Site contents --> Select **New** --> Select **App** OR select **Add an app** from settings (gear) icon
2. On "My Apps" page, select **From my organization**

   [image]
3. Select **classic experience** link

   [image]
4. It will open classic experience "Your Apps" page where you can search for & add "Picture Library"

   [image]

---

**Additional**:

You can directly go to classic experience "Your Apps" page using URL in below format:

```
<site-url>/_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx
```