# Can I easily link from one item to another in the Issue Tracker template?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, modern-experience, issue-tracking

This is my first time using the Issue Tracker template in (O365) SharePoint.  Other issue-tracking systems typically have some kind of shorthand where you can write `#123` or `MYPROJ-123` in the body of an issue, and create a link that takes the reader to another issue in the same repository.

More advanced trackers typically have a button to click to insert such a link, or real-time parsing so that typing "#" shows a typeahead-search dropdown listing matching issues.

I don't expect such advanced functionality out of SharePoint, but it would be nice to be able to refer from one issue to another without having to find the first issue, copy a link to it, then paste that into the second issue.  Is there any kind of shorthand I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below suggestions which might work for you:

**Option 1**: Create a new lookup column in "modern" issue tracker list which will get the information from same list. Using lookup column, you can select the related issues from same list.

[image]

**Option 2**: You can use classic experience "Issue Tracking" template which will allow you to select the "Related Issues":

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into option 1 now.  For option 2, how do I switch to "classic experience"?  I created the tracker by just picking "New -> List" from the site home page, where I saw the Issue Tracker template.  Is "classic" a different template?

Comment: Yes, classic template is different. Follow my answer given on [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298103/issue-with-adding-app-option/298104#298104) for searching & creating a new list with classic "Issue Tracking" template. Which site template are you using, communication or team site?

Comment: I'm just a user, so I'm not really sure how to answer about the site template.  It has `/teams/` in the URL and is linked to a Teams group, so maybe "team site"?

Comment: Ok, if you are using team site, you should be able to create classic issue tracker list as well.